# pip upgrade problems on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pip

I try to upgrade pip with **pip install -U pip** and I get:

Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.0
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.0:

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip'

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are getting a permission error, try running your command as super user:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have permission to write to the system folder. You can avoid the problem by installing the packages to the user folder. So this is the code you have to use for upgrading the pip.

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

add `python` to your command with --`user`. It should work

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```